# How do you configure static DHCP (based on MAC addresses) on Adtran NetVanta 3200?

Tags: configuration, router, dhcp, networking

we have an Adtran NetVanta, and I was wondering how (if possible) to configure static DHCP entries for specific devices on the network?  The NetVanta 3200 is running OS v15.08.00.  Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes also referred to as "DHCP Reservation".  Have you checked the product documentation for that term as well?

Comment: I have, and I did not see anything.

Answer (score 2):

```
ip dhcp-server pool "name"
  dns-server H.H.H.H
  default-router H.H.H.H
  host N.N.N.N S.S.S.S
  hardware-address XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX ethernet
```

Comment: This is correct, but offers no explanation. The confusing aspect of doing this on an Adtran is simply that it views a static assignment as an entirely separate IP address pool. Where it gets weirder is that you can't exclude that assigned address from any pool that can assign from that address range, or it won't assign them at all, static hardware assigned address or not.